# How can I recall a futureprovider (riverpod) on build

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a simple page, which shows a product, and i am trying to use riverpod, and futureprovider, but the future is only called the first time i go to the page?

```
final productInfo = FutureProvider<Map<String, dynamic>>((ref) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://www.api.com/$clickedID');
  final content = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return content;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With the recent Riverpod, you can do `ref.refresh(userProvider)` to refresh the provider.

Answer (score 1):

There are a two options.

1. ref.refresh(provider)
2. ref.invalidate(provider)

Note that if you are using a AsyncValue, the old result will be returned when you refresh the FutureProvider and AsyncValue.isRefreshing will be set to true:

```
final notificationRepositoryProvider = FutureProvider<bool?>((ref) async {
  Future<bool> approveDocument() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => Future.value(Random().nextBool()));

  return approveDocument();
});

class HomeView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeViewState createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends ConsumerState<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AsyncValue<bool?> rejectResponse = ref.watch(notificationRepositoryProvider);
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // ref.refresh(notificationRepositoryProvider);
          ref.watch(notificationRepositoryProvider).;
        },
        child: rejectResponse.when(
          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          skipLoadingOnRefresh: false,
          error: (err, stack) => Text('Error'),
          data: (data) => Text('Yes: $data'),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
final userProvider = StreamProvider<User>(
 final response =
      await http.get('https://www.api.com/$clickedID');
  final content = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return content;
);
```

now you can listen to the provider using `watch`,

```
  AsyncValue<User> user = watch(userProvider);
```

Comment: Then i get a type error, with Future<type> cant be assigned to Stream<type>

Comment: use stream builder rather than the future builder.

Comment: Okay thanks, will this work even if it's not a stream?

Answer (score 0):

No inbuilt functionality, but you can override the value with the same future at a later time.

```
recallProductInfoFutureProvider() {
final response = http.get('https://www.api.com/$clickedID');
  final content = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
productInfo.overrideWithValue(content)
}
```

Consider using with StreamProvider and watching inside Consumer to update UI on overrideWithValue.